# How to change date format in model of attribute in sails.js?

Tags: javascript, java

How we can set the date format of attribute in model from `Tue Apr 12 2016 17:16:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` to `2016-04-12 17:16:12`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need :

```
inputDate.format("isoDateTime");
```